# Use self-defined operator symbol simplify formula

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, operators

Mathematica is very useful and powerful in symbol compute, but some output isn’t concise if we didn’t simplify.

Can i predefined some operator? eg. [Lie bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields). Here is a minimum example.

Suppose bracket operator is $[x, y]= xy-yx$, and $\hat{a} b=  a \times b$ ([Hat operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_operator)). Here $x,y,a, b$ are vector (fields).

If some output in Mathematica is

`2*X[t]*y[t]-2*y[t]*x[t] + CrossProduct[3*a,b]`

Can i simplify it as $2[x,y]+3\hat{a} b$, the form in most Math books?

I find a lots of [similar discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211083/simplifying-the-expression-by-defining-functions) (It use self-defined `Functions` to simplify the expression by `FullSimplify`), but i think it’s important in symbol computing and simplifying by self-defined operators. In this way, output will not the function Name eg. `liebracket[x_,y_]=x y - y x` , we may let symbol operator appear in formula, eg `[x,y]`.

Any comments will be much appreciate!